# Maven: antrun plugin builds JAR file -> How can i install/deploy it in my repository?

Tags: java, maven, ant, build, repository

I am in the middle of an Ant -> Maven migration project and I have a question (I'm not really a Maven expert), since I'm stuck at a particular point:

Within one of my pom.xml files I have to use the maven-antrun-plugin to call an external ANT file, which builds a jar file and puts it in a temporary folder. There is no alternative to this call. Everything is working fine - the ant script works as it should, but how can I "package" this jar in the usual Maven workflow?

I know that I could manually call the `mvn install:install-file`, but isn't there a possibility to configure my pom.xml in a way that the above generated jar file IS actually the artifact of that pom.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you use the [build helper maven plugin's attach artifact goal](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html) to attach your extra *.jar to the maven module that triggered its creation.

since having a single maven module produce more than one artifact is generally a bad idea it would be best if you isolate this in a maven module of type pom so that this would be its only artifact

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i was looking for. The intention was already to only produce a single artifact (the jar is the only goal for this submodule). I just had to change the packacking to "pom" in my pom.xml.